Do these hadiths regarding tall buildings exist?
Do these narrations exist?

“(The barefoot, naked, deaf and dumb) are the top leaders of the people” This means the kings of the earth as explicitly stated in al-Isma‘īlī’s narrations, and Abū Farwa names the kings in his narrations. Those meant are the people of the desert, as explicitly stated in Sulayman al-Taymī’s and other narrations: “Who are the barefoot and naked?” He replied: “The little Arabs (al-‘urayb).” (Another website also cites Sulayman al-Taymī saying "the Bedouin Arabs.")

The closest I've found is Musnad Ahmad Hambal 2924 but that just says "The Arabs." Are these prophecies real?

Yes the hadith referred to in your quote exists, it is the well known hadith of Gabriel. The relevant parts being:

وإذا كان الحفاة العراة رءوس الناس فذاك من أشراطها
When the bare-footed naked people become the chiefs of the people, that will be of its portents
— Bukhari


إذا رأيت الحفاة العراة الصم البكم ملوك الأرض فذاك من أشراطها
And when you see barefooted, naked, deaf and dumb as the kings of the earth - then that is [one] of its signs
— Muslim\


قال: إذا رأيت العالة الحفاة العراة يتطاولون في البناء وكانوا ملوكا قال: ما العالة الحفاة العراة قال: العريب
The Prophet ﵌ said: "When you see the destitute, barefoot and naked ones competing in construction of tall buildings and becoming kings"
The man asked: "Who are the destitute, barefoot and naked ones?"
The Prophet ﵌ said: "al-‘urayb" (diminutive form of Arabs)
— Sahih Ibn Hibban


Respectfully, where in Sahih Ibn Hibban does it say that specific hadith was narrated by Sulayman al-Tahmi?
